# Add click event to dynamically added button to kendo window content

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-window

I have kendo window and im adding content dynamically to kendo window.
The content has a button and i wanted to attach click event to that button.
jQuery is able to find the button from the content, attach click event however click event never gets fired

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmj09ok0/7/)

**Html**

```
<div id="example">
  <div id="window">     
   </div> 
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
          $(document).ready(function() {                 
                    // in reality this contnet will be returned from ajax call
                    var dynamicContent  ="<div><button id='btn' type='button'>Click Me</button></div>"
                    var myWindow = $("#window")
                    var button = $(dynamicContent).find("#btn");

                    // show number of buttons found.                    
                    alert("found " + button.length + " button")

                    // attach click event to button
                                        button.click(function(){
                      alert("this is test");                      
                    })

                    myWindow.kendoWindow({
                        width: "600px",
                        height:"200px",
                        title: "My Window"
                    }).data("kendoWindow").center().open().content(dynamicContent);
                });
```

Comment: you select your not even yet created button with jQuery before you actualy inserted it into the DOM.
I don't know the kendo api, but I would look for an event that is called when the content changes, and then execute the button code as callback.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
button.click(function(){
  alert("this is test");                      
})
```

to

```
$('#window').on('click', 'button', function(){
  alert("this is test");                      
})
```

As you mentioned the element is dynamically created, so it is not part of the browsers dom structure, and therefore can't be selected with jQuery. Using the above code, jQuery listens for any changes to the dom structure inside the `#window` element, so you can then select any dynamically created elements.